Reflexitivity of sobolev spaces
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open 
I'm interested to understand the reflexivity property of Sobolev spaces $W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ for $p \in [1, +\infty]$, using the fact that $L^p(\Omega)$ are reflexive for $p \in (1, +\infty)$ and that $L^1(\Omega)$ and $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ aren't reflexive.
In particular, since $W^{1, p}(\Omega) < (L^p(\Omega))^{n+1}$ is (norm)-closed subspaces  $\forall p \in [1, +\infty]$, is trivially to conclude that $W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ are reflexive  $\forall p \in (1, +\infty)$
Moreover is well know that $W^{1, 1}(\Omega)$ and $W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)$ are not reflexive. To show these two fact i have two different idea:

To show the non-reflexivity of $W^{1, 1}(\Omega)$ we can use that in a reflexive space every (norm)-bounded sequence admits an a weakly convergent subsequence and construct an absurd on this. In particular we can think to a sequence that converge $L^1$-weakly to Heaviside function and with sequence of gradient that converge star-weakly in the sense of radon measure to the Dirac-delta.

To show the non-reflexivity of $W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)$ for example is sufficient to show that there exists an a closed subspace that is isomorphic as Banach space (i.e Linear+Homeomophism) to $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. In particular my professor suggested me to think at the radial functions as a guess for this subspace, but i'm totally stuck.


So my question is if the idea of 1) seems to be correct and if someone can help me for 2), also reporting a possible reference for 2) would be very useful.

Instead of proving the existence of a closed subspace of $ W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) $ that is isomorphic (as a Banach space) to $ L^\infty(\Omega) $, we show that there is a closed subspace of $ W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) $ isomorphic to a closed subspace of $ L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.
Let $ x_0 \in \Omega $ and $ R > 0 $ such that $ B_R(x_0) \subset \Omega $. We aim to construct a subspace consisting of compactly supported radial functions in $ \Omega $. Specifically, we consider functions $ u(x) = U(|x - x_0|) $, where $ U \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+) = \mathrm{Lip}_{b}(\mathbb{R}^+) $ and $ U(t) \equiv 0 $ for $ t > R $. Given $ f \in L^\infty([0, R]) $, define
$$
u(x) = U(|x - x_0|) = \int_{|x - x_0|}^R f(t) \, dt.
$$
Thus, we have embedded $ L^\infty([0, R]) $ into $ W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) $. Next, we show that this embedding induces an equivalence of norms.
Clearly, $\lVert f \rVert _{L^\infty([0, R])} \leq R \|U\|_{W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+)}.$ 
Conversely, we can immediately estimate
$$ \lVert U\rVert_{L^\infty} \leq R \|f\|_{L^\infty([0, R])}.$$
On the other hand, since $ U \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+) = \mathrm{Lip}_{b}(\mathbb{R}^+) $, it is differentiable almost everywhere by Rademacher's theorem. Therefore, we can estimate the gradient as
$$
\|\nabla U\|_{L^\infty} \leq \|f(|x - x_0|)\|_{L^\infty([0, R])} = \|f\|_{L^\infty([0, R])}.
$$
Combining these estimates, we obtain
$$
\|U\|_{W^{1,\infty}} \leq (R + 1) \|f\|_{L^\infty}.
$$
This shows that there is an equivalence of norms between $ L^\infty([0, R]) $ and the corresponding subspace of $ W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) $. Consequently, we have constructed a closed subspace of $ W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) $ isomorphic to $ L^\infty([0, R]) $, demonstrating the presence of a non-reflexive subspace in $ W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) $.
